# Continuous function is $0$ for all real number?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

In a book of Bartle we have the following problem:

"Let be $h: \mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ continuous and satisfies 
$$h\left(\frac{m}{2^n}\right)=0, \forall m \in \mathbb{Z}, n \in \mathbb{N}.$$

Prove that $h(x) = 0$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$.

I found that $h(z) = 0$ when $z$ is whole number, being $z= l + \frac{c}{2^n}$ by Euclid's Algorithm, for some $c, l$ whole numbers, and doing $n$ tend to infinity. I think that I can make sequences $(x_p)_{p\in \mathbb{N}}\rightarrow x$, such that these sequences have the form "$\frac{m}{2^n}$". Any suggestions?

Comment: You've got the right idea.  It's easier to build $x_p$ if you express $x$ in binary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this some chapter about number line or some specific stuff?

The sequence idea is good enough. You have to look at neighborhoods of $x$ and show that no matter how small it is, there is always a point of form $\frac{m}{2^n}$ there. So if it's continuous, it's gotta be $0$ everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the fact that your function is sequentially continuous at any point $x\in \mathbb{R}$. That is, if $x_n\to x$, then $h(x_n)\to h(x)$. Now notice that all real numbers can be approximated by a sequence of rational numbers; as $\mathbb{Q}$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$.